# pykafka queued.max.messages.kbytes is outside allowed range

Tags: python, pykafka

I am trying to use **pykafka** with **rdkafka** to consume messages but I am getting the following error while trying to initialize the consumer.

> Configuration property "queued.max.messages.kbytes" value 102400000 is
>   outside allowed range 1..2097151

Following is my code. Can someone help me with resolving this error?

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient(broker)

topic = client.topics['test_topic']

consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer(use_rdkafka=True)
```

Comment: Are you able to figure this out? I'm facing pykafka.exceptions.RdKafkaException: `receive.message.max.bytes` must be >= `fetch.max.bytes` + 512 when using balanced_consumer with rdkafka=True.

Comment: @AjayGuyyala and OP have you solved this? I opened a ticket on their github [here](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/966).

Comment: @MatthewMoisen No, we haven't solved it. We moved ahead with confluent-kafka-python client.

Comment: @AjayGuyyala do you happen to have any guides for `confluent-kafka-python` client? I couldn't find much except from the documentation on Google. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewMoisen, I followed this https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/ and its pretty decent. We got where we have to with that documentation.

Comment: I am successfully passing fetch_message_max_bytes=1024 * 10